# Cibus sanus — healthy food?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, adjective, cibus, duolingo

The Duolingo Latin course uses *sanus* as "healthy" in connection with meals.
A healthy lunch would be *prandium sanum* according to the course.

But I always thought that *sanus* is only refers to the health of a person or some such entity.
I can see how a lunch can help me become *sanus* but not how it could be *sanus* itself.
The Duolingo course appears to be mistaken or at least somewhat unnatural.

At the very least *sanus* appears to mean more "in a healthy state" than "health-inducing".
But is the second meaning — the only one used by Duolingo — correct too?

Comment: I *think* I remember reading that whether food can be _sanus_ was debated by medieval logicians! If someone can find that debate and its results, that might make the perfect answer.

Comment: Googling "[equivocation sanum Boethius](https://www.google.com/search?q=equivocation+sanum+Boethius)" turns up some promising leads. Apparently Aristotle started the conversation, analyzing "healthy" as applied to dogs, their food, and their urine, and the Medievals dug into it further. On a first look, it appears that Boëthius wrote _salutaris_ rather than _sanum_ even when considering this topic.

Comment: Your question shouldn't mention the Duo course, because the course being in beta, I really think they'll fix it soon.

Comment: @Quidam It's not unusual that questions have a context that goes obsolete in time. I think it's better to indicate the origin of the question if it's as clear as inclusion in an online course. What's more, perhaps the Duolingo people follow this site take this discussion as a suggestion for improvement. If they change the wording later, we can always add a note to this question.

Comment: Maybe "online course" would be enough. But if they fix the course, people could think it's an horrible course. I don't know if we could notice they have fixed the course, as there's no notification.

Comment: @Quidam Duolingo is still poorly constructed even now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are right that *sanus* more correctly describes a healthy state, whereas ***saluber/salubris*** seems to be preferred to describe those things which bestow health.  Some examples:

- Climate:

> *ex **saluberrimis** Galliae et Hispaniae*
>
> after the very healthy [climate]* of Gaul and Spain

Caesar, *Civil War*, III.2

*climate is implied because the contrast is with the bad climate of Apulia and Brundisium which is making the troops ill

- Locale:

> *eaque remoto, **salubri**, amoeno loco*
>
> [a house and land of your own] and that in a remote, healthy, and
>   pleasant locality

Cicero, *Letters to Friends*, 333 (VII.20), Cicero to Trebatius, Velia, 20 July 44

- Spa towns:

> ut scribis, **salubres** repente factae sunt
>
> [the resort town of Baiae], as you write, has suddenly become a
>   healthy spot

Cicero, *Letters to Friend*s, 263 (IX.12), Cicero to Dolabella, December 45

- The waters of said spa town:

> *“Non haec, ut fama est, unda **salubris** erat”*
>
> "Those waters [of Baiae] were not, as rumour has it, healthy"

Ovid, *Ars Amatoria*, 258

- Plants/medicine:

> *chelidoniam visui **saluberrimam** hirundines monstravere  …*
>
> celandine was shown to be very healthy for the sight by swallows …

Pliny the Elder, *Natural History*, VIII.XLI

- And, finally, food and drink:

> *ceu non **saluberrimum** ad potus aquae liquorem natura dederit, quo
>   cetera omnia animantia utuntur*
>
> [speaking of water] as if nature had not given us the most healthy of
>   beverages to drink, which all other animals make use of

Pliny the Elder, *Natural History*, XIV.XXVIII

> *tostum **salubrius** habetur*
>
> [chickpea] is healthier roasted

Pliny the Elder, *Natural History*, XXII.LXXII

Comment: That really seems the most appropriate word. It combines (for me, at any rate) the ideas of _salus_ and _uber_ : as you might put it, 'a fertile (source) of health'. Surely the sense that Duolingo was looking for and the word they should have chosen. My suggestion of metonymy is all very well, but  _saluber_ makes the selection of _sanus_ quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

I think the first problem here is that there are far more references to gourmandising in the classical sources than to the effects of food on health. Think, for example, of Horace Sat. II, iv *passim*, and the alleged habit of the Emperor Vitellius of self-induced vomiting to make room for more!

More simply, though they possibly had what we commonly call 'food fads', they don't seem to have cared about much beyond an actual pleasure in food. I can't be sure, of course, but I suspect that vegetarian, and more certainly vegan diets were seldom chosen deliberately.

My reaction was to consult the article on *cibus* in the *Gradus ad Parnassum* [1]. None of the actual epithets noted (but none with a source given) — *sapidus, dulcis, gratus, laetus, regius, solennis, opimus, utilis, parcus, vilis, mendicatus* — particularly suggests healthy eating. The quoted phrases, *corpora sustentans, instaurans vires, animique vigorem* etc. give no help.

Perhaps the case is that the ancients just weren't 'into' dietary terms, such as 'healthy eating' in a fashion compatible with our modern ideas. On the other hand, if there isn't an exact epithet to match the 'healthy' that we apply to food, I see no reason not to use *cibus sanus* metonymically if the context is clear.

[1] The *Gradus* was published in 1813, but it is still considered authoritative, not necessarily as comprehensive as a modern compilation would be.

Comment: Food can be _laetus_?? That's sounds to me even odder than saying that food can be _sanus._

Comment: @Ben Kovitz That's what it says in the Gradus! It's actually printed _lætus_ in two different editions. My guess is a misprint for _lautus_ — splendid, sumptuous etc.

Comment: @BenKovitz It's possible that *laetus* is a transferred epithet.

Answer (score 4):

Just based on the meaning of the word, [salutaris](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/salutaris) might be a better choice. I'm not sure if it was ever used that way but it seems to make more sense.

Comment: Certainly, if you don't accept metonymy, _salutaris_ would be more sensible than the _sanus_ used in Duolingo